# Multidimentional associative array sorting by value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the associative array which I need to sort by value:

```
Array
(
    ['group_1'] => Array
        (
            ['key_1'] => Array
                 (
                      ['field_1'] = 'someval',
                      ['order'] = 2
                 )
            ['key_2'] => Array
                 (
                      ['field_1'] = 'someval',
                      ['order'] = 0
                 )
        )

    ['group_2'] => Array
        (
            ...
        )
)
```

I am trying to sort each 'group_N' array by 'order' field with usort():

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['order'] == $b['order']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['order'] < $b['order']) ? -1 : 1;
}

foreach ($result_array as $group => $values) {      
        uasort($values, "cmp");         
}
```

But no success.
How can I do it?

Comment: You sort the local `$values` variable that is not stored anywhere. `$result_array[$group] = $values;`

Comment: pass `$values` by reference. `foreach($result_array as &$group => &$value)`. honestly, i think it would be better to use array map with an anonymous function containing the sort as opposed to a foreach, but thats just me.

Comment: @r3wt 1. `array_map` does accept a copy of an array 2. It does not work with keys 3. Mutations/mutability is not cool ;;-)

Comment: @zerkms oh you're right, but `array_walk` does.

Comment: @r3wt now better :-) Why don't you like `foreach` btw? Those are 2 lines of code (what could be easier to read/maintain?!) that you suggest to replace with `1 + N` additional function calls + overhead of creating an anonymous function.

Comment: @zerkms i suppose we should bench mark?

Comment: @r3wt without doubts `array_walk` will be slower, consume more memory and (subjective) be more difficult to understand

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because its title is too generic and will draw future visitors to it for the wrong reasons, when the *actual* problem is rather unrelated to sorting arrays.

Comment: @deceze You could [edit] the title instead of closing the question...

Comment: @hichris123 Then I'd actually just close it as duplicate of some existing question. This problem is not exactly new... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Passing arguments by reference as suggested solved the problem.

Working excellently with:

```
foreach ($result_array as $group => &$values) {      
    uasort($values, "cmp");         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to modify an array in a `foreach` loop, you must pass the key/val by reference like so

```
foreach ($result_array as &$group => &$values) {      
        uasort($values, "cmp");         
}
```

or use `array walk()` (according to @zerkms this is slower, so probably a bad idea)

```
array_walk($array,
   function(&$row){
       uasort($row, "cmp");
   }
);
```

[demo using array walk](http://3v4l.org/60vDV)